# Consequences of sub-exponential proofs/algorithms for SAT

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, proof-complexity

Would there be any major consequences if SAT had at most subexponential unsat proofs or even more strongly, SAT had subexponential-time algorithms?

Comment: It would disprove the [exponential time hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis) which has various consequences (covered in the wikipedia article).

Comment: @ArtemKaznatcheev comment -> answer ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat feels kind of awkward to give an answer when Ryan Williams can provide a much better one. I gave one for now, but I hope Ryan and others pitch in with something cooler.

Comment: If the answer is correct, it doesn't matter who gives it :)

Comment: Sorry Artem, my answer wouldn't be much cooler than yours... I guess one thing to add would be that ETH is false implies new superlinear circuit lower bounds (same paper).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If SAT had a subexponential-time algorithm, the you would disprove the [exponential time hypothesis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_time_hypothesis).

For fun consequences: if you showed that circuit SAT over AND,OR,NOT with $n$ variables and $poly(n)$ circuit gates can be solved faster than the trivial $2^n poly(n)$ approach, then by [Ryan Williams' paper](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ryanw/improved-algs-lbs2.pdf) you show that $NEXP \not\subseteq P/poly$.

Comment: I think that the first paragraph of your answer is just the definition of the exponential time hypothesis.