# Potentially stronger form of non-$ETH$

Tags: ds.algorithms, sat

If we have a $2^{n^a}$ algorithm to $K$-$SAT$ where $a<1$ for all $K>2$ then $ETH$ fails and literature gives consequences. What are the consequences if $a=o(1)$?

Comment: The title and question don't match. The assertion that there is no $2^{n^a}$-time algorithm for $k$-SAT with $a = o(1)$ is a weaker statement than ETH.

Comment: $2^{n^{1/\log\log n}}$ falls under $2^{n^{o(1)}}$ while $2^{n^{0.99999}}$ falls under $2^{n^a}$ with $a<1$.

Comment: Yes, and $2^{n^{1/\log \log n}} = o(2^{n^{0.9999}})$, so asserting that there is no $2^{n^{1/\log \log n}}$-time algorithm for $k$-SAT is weaker than asserting that there is no $2^{n^{0.9999}}$-time algorithm.

Comment: Is this question sort of the same? https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9237/consequences-of-sub-exponential-proofs-algorithms-for-sat

Comment: ETH is related to 3-SAT, but not for k-SAT [the SETH is related to k-SAT with different definition than ETH]

Comment: @YOUSEFY both conjectures are very related through the sparsification lemma. SETH implies ETH

Answer (score 4):

If $\alpha \in O\left(\frac{\log\log n}{ \log n}\right)$, then you would have proved that $P = NP$, since $n^{\alpha} \in O(\log n)$ and $2^{n^{\alpha}} \in O(\mathrm{poly}(n))$.

On the other hand, for $\alpha \in \omega\left(\frac{\log\log n}{ \log n}\right)$ and $\alpha \in o(1)$, I think the most interesting thing that happens is breaking **ETH** with all its consequences (including breaking **SETH** and many other conditional lower-bounds on polynomial and parameterized problems).

Comment: You mean $\alpha \in \omega (\frac{\log \log n}{\log n})$